# How do I format 12 hour data with am/pm without NAs?

Tags: r, datetime

The reformatting works for just the date, but when I add in the am/pm data it doesn't work. Here is the code and data:

```
str(Hourly_Steps$activity_hour)
 chr [1:22099] "4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM" "4/12/2016 1:00:00 AM" ...
```

This worked to format just the date...

```
    > day <- strptime(Hourly_Steps$activity_hour, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S")
> day
  [1] "2016-04-12 00:00:00 IST" "2016-04-12 01:00:00 IST"
  [3] "2016-04-12 02:00:00 IST" "2016-04-12 03:00:00 IST"
  [5] "2016-04-12 04:00:00 IST" "2016-04-12 05:00:00 IST"
  [7] "2016-04-12 06:00:00 IST" "2016-04-12 07:00:00 IST"
  [9] "2016-04-12 08:00:00 IST" "2016-04-12 09:00:00 IST"
 [11] "2016-04-12 10:00:00 IST" "2016-04-12 11:00:00 IST"
```

But when I try add in the %p for am/pm info, it goes back to 24hr...

```
    > day <- strptime(Hourly_Steps$activity_hour, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
> day
  [1] "2016-04-12 00:00:00 IST" "2016-04-12 01:00:00 IST"
  [3] "2016-04-12 02:00:00 IST" "2016-04-12 03:00:00 IST"
  [5] "2016-04-12 04:00:00 IST" "2016-04-12 05:00:00 IST"
  [7] "2016-04-12 06:00:00 IST" "2016-04-12 07:00:00 IST"
  [9] "2016-04-12 08:00:00 IST" "2016-04-12 09:00:00 IST"
 [11] "2016-04-12 10:00:00 IST" "2016-04-12 11:00:00 IST"
 [13] "2016-04-12 12:00:00 IST" "2016-04-12 13:00:00 IST"
 [15] "2016-04-12 14:00:00 IST" "2016-04-12 15:00:00 IST"
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `%y` is for a 2-digit year, you need `%Y` for a four-digit year. The offset difference from meant the rest of the time wouldn't parse well, hence the `NA` values.

Comment: (Also notice in your example that your input 2016 dates show up as year 2020, because you only looked at the first 2 digits of the year.)

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks, using the correct %Y helped fix most of the problem, I'll update the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works correctly.

You are starting with a `"character"` vector, and `strptime()` correctly reads your imperial time into `"POSIXt"` time format. The `"POSIXt"` is **only** stored in this specific `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS TZ"` format and this is what you see displayed.

```
x <- c("4/12/2016 1:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 1:00:00 PM", "4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM",
       "4/12/2016 12:00:00 PM")

y <- strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
y
# [1] "2016-04-12 01:00:00 CEST" "2016-04-12 13:00:00 CEST"
# [3] "2016-04-12 00:00:00 CEST" "2016-04-12 12:00:00 CEST"
```

and

```
class(y)
# [1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

Maybe you are looking for a way to change your output format, where you'd want to use `strftime()`.

```
z <- strftime(y, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
z
# [1] "04/12/2016 01:00:00 am" "04/12/2016 01:00:00 pm"
# [3] "04/12/2016 12:00:00 am" "04/12/2016 12:00:00 pm"
```

Note, however, that you now have a `"character"` class.

```
class(z)
# [1] "character"
```

So, altogether you may want:

```
strftime(strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'), '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
# [1] "12/04/2016 01:00:00 am" "12/04/2016 01:00:00 pm"
# [3] "12/04/2016 12:00:00 am" "12/04/2016 12:00:00 pm"
```

***Sidenote:*** Midnight may not be displayed even though it is stored internally.

```
strptime("4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM", '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
# [1] "2016-04-12 CEST"
```

Comment: Thanks, this explains the issue. Ideally I'd like to change the data to 24hr time in datetime class. Do you know a simple way to do this?

Comment: I actually stumbled on how to do this earlier: 'date_time <- strptime(Hourly_Steps$activity_hour, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz="UTC")'

Comment: @CrashBandicoot Actually `y` has 24hr, I just confused day and month (updated).